# Selecting a sum() from a secondary table and joining with a first select

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am using knex.js library to select data from a first table called "empresas" and i am trying to get the sum('sucursales.dotacion as sum') from a second table called "sucursales".

So far i have this working code using the knex.js library for node.js

```
knex.schema.raw("SET sql_mode=''").then(() => {
    knex.select('*')
    .from('empresas')
    .leftJoin('sucursales', 'empresas.id', 'sucursales.id_empresas')
    .sum('sucursales.dotacion as sum')
    .groupBy('sucursales.id_empresas')
    .then((rows) => {
        for (row of rows) {


        result  +=  `${row['id']}` + "," 
                    + `${row['rut']}` + ","
                    + `${row['empresa']}` + ","
                    + `${row['razon_social']}` + ","
                    + `${row['email']}` + ","
                    + `${row['sum']}`
        result  += "<br/>";
        }

        res.send(JSON.stringify({ Sum : result}));
    })

})
```

My problem the output is only for the id's that are in both tables and i need all id's from the table "empresas" and when there is no sum() just set it to NULL or 0.

So far i tried inner Join, left and right Join, i get an error on full outer join.

```
knex.select('empresas.id','empresas.rut','empresas.razon_social','empresas.email','sucursales.id_empresas','sucursales.dotacion')
```

How should i make the mysql join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fields having the same name in both tables that you are joining. You need to explicitly list the fields that you want to select, else mysql will pick any of the duplicated fields (in you use case, it seems like the id that comes from sucursales is picked, which yields NULL if the left join did not succeed).

This :

```
knex.select('*')
```

Should be written as :

```
knex.select('empresas.id')
```

Also the GROUP BY clause should relate to empresas.id instead of sucursales.id.

Comment: i tried using knex('empresas.id','empresas.rut','empresas.razon_social','empresas.email') and i still get only the rows where the id is on both tables

Comment: @IngolfKrauss : I think you need to change the GROUP BY too, I updated my answer.